# Regular Expression does not match charcter within a pattern - Google Enhanced campaign

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, google-ads-api

I am looking to do following using a regular expression
From   string txt = "http://{ifnotmobile:www.abc.com}{ifmobile:m.abc.com}/?creative={ifnotmobile:1234}";

Expecting the following output  http://abc.com/?creative=1234

{ifmobile: should be replaced by the value after it till the next “}” is reached. Any block for “{Ifnotmobile: should be removed. Please note that there can be multiple of such blocks.

The problem I am facing is that the whole string “www.abc.com}{ifmobile:m.abc.com}/?creative={ifnotmobile:1234”  is matched  as the word. While only www.abc.com should have matched. I am unable to stop the matching at the first “}” after “{ifmobile:”.

String txt = "http://{ifnotmobile:www.abc.com}{ifmobile:m.abc.com}/?creative={ifnotmobile:1234}";

```
    Regex ifnotmobileRegex = new Regex("(\\{)(ifnotmobile:)((?:.*))(\\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    MatchCollection matchColl = ifnotmobileRegex.Matches(txt);

    foreach (Match match in matchColl)
    {

        String c1 = match.Groups[1].ToString();
        String c2 = match.Groups[2].ToString();

        String word = match.Groups[3].ToString();
        String c3 = match.Groups[4].ToString();
        String machingPattern = c1 + c2 + word + c3;

        txt = txt.Replace(machingPattern, word);

    }

    Regex ifmobileRegex = new Regex("(\\{)(ifmobile:)((?:.*))(\\})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    MatchCollection matchColl2 = ifmobileRegex.Matches(txt);

    foreach (Match match in matchColl2)
    {

        String c1 = match.Groups[1].ToString();
        String c2 = match.Groups[2].ToString();

        String word = match.Groups[3].ToString();
        String c3 = match.Groups[4].ToString();
        String machingPattern = c1 + c2 + word + c3;

        txt = txt.Replace(machingPattern, "");
    }

    Response.Write("<br>");

    Response.Write(txt);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to stop the matching at the first “}” after “{ifmobile:”.

```
.*? }  //any character non-greedy, closing brace
```

or:

```
[^}]* }  //not a closing brace, closing brace
```

You'll have to escape the braces in the way that's appropriate for your language.

But according to the rules you set forth, the expected output would be:

```
http://m.abc.com/?creative=
```

A simpler approach may be to split() on "{ifnotmobile [^}] }" to remove those clauses, join() the pieces back together, then do a regex replacement for the ifmobile clauses.

Comment: Thanks Stud.I too think that a mix of string search and replacement and regex logic might work.